# How to use never in sentences

Tags: adverbs

As a general rule

If the verb is am/are/is/was the adverb **never** is placed after the verb

Example -

> I am **never** late for school

But in the following sentence

> I am determined **never** to yield this point

**never** is used after **determined**

I think the sentence should be

> I am **never** determined to yield this point.

Am I right in this analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; that would entirely change the meaning of the sentence, from saying you are never going to yield to saying you are never determined. It would be like changing

> I am certain I will never win.

to

> I am never certain I will win.

Think of "never" as meaning "not ever" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/never) - then you want to say that you will not ever yield, not that you are not ever determined.